# Indenting in Python 3.8 Please fix

Tags: python, indentation

So I want to make a login page but indentation is getting in the way, I'm new to Python and whatever I do seems to keep messing it up.

```
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")

password = input("Enter your password: ")

    else:
    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")

return StartingPrompt
```

Comment: Could you please add the error traceback you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation was messed up.

```
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
else:
    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you initialize StartingPrompt somewhere else, your code should look as follows:

```py
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
else:
    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")
```

After every `if` statement, you need an indented block; the same goes for `def`(functions), `try-except`, etc.

For example:

```
if <condition>:
    # indent
    print("Inside if-body.")
elif <condition>:
    # indent
    print("Inside elif-body.")
else:
    # indent
    print("Inside else-body.")

# back to original indentation
print("Outside of if-statment.")
```

You also have a `return` statement, but you do not need this as your code is not contained within a function. If you would like to use a function:

```
def login():
    # indent here (inside function body)
    StartingPrompt = input("Please enter option: ")
    if StartingPrompt == "l":
        username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
    else:
        print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")
    return StartingPrompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your indentation (near the `password`,`else`,`return`):

```
def YOUR_FUNCTION():
    if StartingPrompt == "l":
        username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ") 
    else:
        print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")

    return StartingPrompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments for clarity.

```
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")

    password = input("Enter your password: ")  # one tab indent here

else:  # one un-indent here
    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")

return StartingPrompt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are use to programming but try to think python indent as the () in other language. Indent in python is the same as layer. You need to stay at the same layer unless you have finished your statement.

```
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")

    password = input("Enter your password: ") #you can t go down because your if statement isn't over 

else: #else statement of a given if statment is at the same level of the if statement

    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 4 spaces for indentation. Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a more styling guide.

```
if StartingPrompt == "l":
    username_2 = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
else:
    print("Please only enter 's' or 'l' ")

return StartingPrompt
```